# Open application through file association into specific code

Tags: c#, file, associations

A file association has been added to the system (called `.uenc`) at which whenever I double click a file with `.uenc` extension, it opens up to my application, which is fine. But I need my application to retrieve the file's full path with file name and input it to a text box within the application.

[image]

> The file with `.uenc` extension

[image]

> I need to enter the file path into the text box next to `Browse` button.

How is this done?

Comment: Explorer will pass the file name clicked to your app as a command line argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make your file association with parameter placeholder like this:

```
yourprogram "%1"
```

In that case you will receive the full path of the file as argument. 
Take in account that your should wrapp the placeholder in quotation marks to deal with spaces in the path.

Comment: How can I do this? I use Visual Studio's `File Associations` feature to add my associations.

Comment: Look at [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/630ed1d9-73f1-4cc0-bc84-04f29cffc13b/what-registry-keys-are-responsible-for-file-extension-association?forum=netfxbcl)